# Drawing grids in tkinter Treeview

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, treeview

I have created a tkinter table with Treeview.
But I cant draw vertical and horizontal lines between the cells.
I want an aesthetic look for my table.

I tries using all possible styles, and read the documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#treeview
but i cant find any solution for this.

```
    TreeView = ttk.Treeview(workers_main_frame,
                            columns=('ID','NAME','EMAIL','PHONE','DEPARTMENT','HIRE DATE'))
    TreeView.place(x=20,y=120,relwidth=0.8,relheight=0.75)

    style = ttk.Style()
    style.theme_use("clam")
    style.configure("Treeview",
                    fieldbackground="white",
                    rowheight=50    ,
                    background="white")
    style.configure("Treeview.Heading", font=("Kerning",11))

    style.map("Treeview",
        background=[("selected", "gray25")],
        foreground=[("selected","white")])


    #creating the headings for the table
    TreeView.heading('#0', text="ID",anchor="w")
    TreeView.column("#0", width=50, anchor='w')
    TreeView.heading('#1', text="NAME",anchor="w")
    TreeView.column("#1", minwidth=180, anchor='w')
    TreeView.heading('#2', text="EMAIL",anchor="w")
    TreeView.column("#2", minwidth=180, anchor='w')
    TreeView.heading('#3', text="PHONE",anchor="w")
    TreeView.column("#3", width=180, anchor='w')
    TreeView.heading('#4', text="DEPARTMENT",anchor="w")
    TreeView.column("#4", width=180, anchor='w')
    TreeView.heading('#5', text="HIRE DATE",anchor="w")
    TreeView.column("#5", width=100, anchor='w')
```

Comment: As you already know, that's not supported.